# Web Sockets failing connection / Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

The problem is, it Used to work.. And then i decided to change my frontend css framework, and then it stopped working. even though the code is the exact same.

my asgi.py file

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import apps.conversation.routing as conversation_routing
import apps.twikkerprofile.routing as core_routing
import apps.feed.routing as feed_routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'twikker.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            conversation_routing.websocket_urlpatterns +
            core_routing.websocket_urlpatterns +
            feed_routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

My routing.py files all follow this pattern:

```
from django.urls import path

from apps.feed import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/tweek/', consumers.TweekConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path('ws/like/', consumers.LikeConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

The websockets declaration in the frontend:

```
 const tweekSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
        + 'tweek/'
    );

    const likeSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
        + 'like/'
    );
```

And the errors I get in the console:
[image]

Edit:
When I start the server, this is what I get

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 24, 2022 - 11:37:50
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'twikker.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

But I guess it should be Starting ASGI/Channels, doesnt it?

Comment: are you using `Brave Browser` by any chance ?

Comment: No, only chrome and edge

Comment: Don't look at the error msg as ASGI is not overriding the WSGI server here yet. Check your daphne installation & settings.

Comment: How can I do that?
I have the channels in INSTALLED_APPS, i have the ASGI reference in settings, so I really dont know what to do

Comment: I think maybe DjangoRestFramework imports is messing up the ASGI

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I followed a youtube tutorial, where I only did "pip install  channels", and added "channels" to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py,
But after reading the channels docs, I saw i should actualy "pip install -U channels["daphne"]" and add "daphne" to INSTALLED_APPS,
then it worked